# C++ Char array to Hex using std::hex

Tags: c++, std

I'm having trouble converting a char array to hexadecimal correctly using `std::hex`.
Here is some example code:

```
char data[240] = ...
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(data); ++i) {
    printf("%02X", (unsigned char)data[i]);
}
printf("\n\n");

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(data); ++i) {
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::uppercase << (unsigned short)data[i];
}
```

Here is the output:

```
14000000E9DE05629F963FE5EC98760401001001EFA8C7561800000001000000020000004494C6924001A8C02C6EFA003A000000B80000003800000004000000EC9876040100100116DC0300BE6D5A924001A8C000000000E33FC65663EFE1560100E4780000010000FA050000000000B6294CC5BC4AAF09DB1F96EAD3EC3E333EF46A46D76E700CDACE12916F2764EB107F3D47FEF46A757BDAA2EEB87523B5CEA526810102E0AF74B55CB172ACF160FC9314B80AFD1D3F8DF143CAA17575A1FE788BBD599B747B33F2BAEC09B18DF4AF7E91D59270FB815C865D25FFDCE794C7F87671207036E060FFAC7E65F61999

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
```

As you can see the result from using `std::hex` doesn't match the correct `printf` version. `FF` is being inserted where it shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `unsigned char data[240]`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah! That did it, thank you!

Comment: For future reference, there's no need to show all 240 values. Just find one or two that are failing and code those. And, oddly enough, when you do that you may well see the problem for yourself.